# What is the max current for a monophase RCCB?

Tags: current

[image: Images tagged with 1 are before the incident, and 2 after the RCCB burned off.]

---

Images tagged with 1 are before the incident, and 2 after the RCCB burned off.

I am guessing that this has happened because of overload. What is the max current for this monophase RCCB?

I could also use some tips to prevent a future incident like this.

---

Whole breakerbox was replaced and the burnt cable cut off. The burn in 2nd image went halfway through the RCCB unit. Thats why I thought it could be because of overload. Am I wrong in assuming the max current should be lower than 40A?

---

Replacement was done by a professional, dont worry. I appreciate the good-will though. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Charles that you should have someone local look at it. But looking at the "before" picture I notice three things. It appears that the insulation has already become deformed (maybe melted). The wire appears to be corroded. There is brown discoloration in the plastic near the screw. So this appears to be a high resistance condition that persisted for some time and caused excessive heating near the wire termination. Whether the root cause is a loose screw or perhaps moisture came in contact with the wire, I don't know.

Comment: Periodic inspection might help prevent recurrence. You can also possibly take thermal images to detect hot spots before anything bad happens. I feel confident in saying that this condition existed for some time prior to the outright failure.

Comment: Whilst the heat damage to the phase connection shows the connection was (relatively) high resistance that doesn't rule out having an overloaded circuit as well. So you should also check that you don't have more than 40 A load on that RCCB. (Do that by adding up the ratings of downstream MCBs and the ratings plates of connected applicances rather than sticking meters in your wiring.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with other posters that this damage was due to long-term overheating of the phase connection. You mentioned the breaker box has been replaced; this should have been done by a professional electrician, qualified in your jurisdiction.

However, to answer your specific question, yes, this RCCB does have a maximum load of 40 A, shown as \$I_n \quad 40A\$ on the case.

Note that this RCCB offers residual current protection only (residual = the difference between the phase and neutral currents). Overload/short circuit protection needs to be provided separately. Typically this means your RCCB will feed MCBs (minature circuit breakers) with a total load not exceeding 40 A. There should also be a supply side fuse/MCB not exceeding 63 A.

The model number is partially missing. It is 5SM1 314-0. The data sheet is available [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/93f5/0900766b80aad6f3.pdf) (via RS).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was probably not due to an overload. It looks more like the terminal screw was not tightened properly. There may also have been some damage to the wire that caused the terminal to overheat. Get someone who knows what they are doing to look at the installation. Asking people on the other side of the world to look at pictures on the internet is no substitute for competent workmanship.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum torque on [that family](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/pd/307966?pdti=td&dl=en&lc=en-DE) is 2.5 Nm. (maximum 3 Nm)

Burns and green copper oxidation  like this are often caused by people not using torque wrenches on these terminals. Causing the wire to be loose, or too tight.
In time due to thermal cycles heat damage will occur. Which eventually causes the wire to burn due to connection resistance.